# How can I pass values from JS to JSCRIPT dynamicly (it drives me nuts)

Tags: javascript, jscript

My home automation system only allows communication through JSCRIPT that runs on the SPS embedded IIS as ASP code. The old web interface was just on HTML and JSCRIPT. I need to move to HTML, CSS and JS with Bootstrap, but for data access I need to stick with JSCRIPT (ASP).
Reading data from asp variables is working easy, set it with a static value as well, **but to set asp variables through JS DYNAMICLY is where I struggle. **

I'd like something likd WritetoASP(A_Var, J_Var) where A_Var has the name of the ASP var and J_Var the value to be passed.

I'm sure that all the experts here do have a solution for me.

Here is a sample Code that shows the challenge.

```
<% @LANGUAGE="JSCRIPT"%>
<%
  var A_Var=88;
 %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>ASP JS HTML Test</title>
<script runat="server" type="text/javascript">
  var J_Var, Par="A_Var";
  /* use the real asp variable name, returns the right ASP value */
  J_Var = <%=A_Var %>;
  document.write ('J_Var = '+J_Var+'<br>');  
  /* write a static value to the asp variable, writes the right value to ASP  */
  <%A_Var = 66;%>;
  document.write ('A_Var = '+<%=A_Var%>+'<br>');  
  /* try to store and use the asp variable name in a JS variable, fails */
  J_Var = <%="Par"%>;
  document.write ('J_Var = '+J_Var+'<br>');  
  /* using eval to execute the asp command, fails */
  J_Var = eval('<%="Par" %>');
  document.write ('J_Var = '+J_Var+'<br>');  
  /* eval execute string generated in a variable, fails */
  /* the replace is needed, otherwise JS interpretes the ASP tag */
  Par="'Ü%="+Par+"%>'";
  document.write ('Par = '+Par+'<br>');  
  J_Var = eval(Par.replace(/Ü/g,"<"));
  document.write ('J_Var = '+J_Var+'<br>');
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>

This is the result:
J_Var = 88
A_Var = 66
J_Var = A_Var
J_Var = A_Var
Par = 'Ü%=A_Var%>'
J_Var = <%=A_Var%>
```

Comment: `<script runat="server" type="text/javascript">` <-- _Wow_ - I haven't seen that in _decades_.

Comment: `J_Var = <%=A_Var %>;` <-- Just to confirm, this is where you're having problems? I'm 95% sure that you can't use `<%=` inside a `<script runat="server">` in Classic ASP because it's a meaningless operation.

Comment: `document.write ('J_Var = '+J_Var+'<br>');` <-- This won't work because there is no `document` object in a `<script runat="server">` in Classic ASP. Also, assuming you actually mean `<script>` (i.e. client-side script) then you should not be using `document.write` anyway, as it completely messes-up the web-page and DOM.

Comment: _"but for data access I need to stick with JSCRIPT (ASP)"_ - **hang on, why**? Even if you're trying to interop with a legacy COM-based system you don't need server-side JScript for that - Also, nowhere in your code do you demonstrate any server-side JScript for data-access.

Comment: Let me sharpen this. I use a Beckhoff CX9010 with TwinCat 2. That rus on a embedded WIN_CE with integrates IIS. The protocol to talk to the thing is TcScript whis is initiated by a ASP command "new ActiveXObject("TcScript.TcScriptSync")". With that you can read and write to the SPS.
Forget about the "runat" it is all about how can i do the static <% A_Var=66%> with a dynamic value instead of the 66 through a Java variable. The document.write is only used to display my trial result. my final program will be much smarter.